# Why do i keep getting Error: Button is not defined in React Native when trying to switch screen?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, expo

When I try to switch screens in React Native, I keep getting the error "Button is not defined". The line of code that seems to be the issue is this one: `navigation.navigate("Game");` inside of my Home.js file, because as soon as I press the "Game" button, the error appears.

Here is my whole code:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import Switch from './src/components/Switch';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <Switch/>
  );
}
```

Switch.js (to switch screen)

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Game from './Game';
import Home from './Home';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const Switch = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Game" component={Game} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default Switch;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native';


const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  const handleButtonPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Game");
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is the Home screen.</Text>
      <Button
        title="Game"
        onPress={handleButtonPress} // Pass the function reference
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I tried to remove the `navigation.navigate("Game");` line and replaced it with `console.log("Pressed");`
When I did that, I didn't get an error.

Comment: did you check whether the navigation props in Home component is correct? console log the navigation props and check if it has navigate function inside.

Comment: Your react-native might be too old. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to use the navigation like this:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
const navigation = useNavigation();


<TouchableOpacity
 onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Game')}
>
 <Text >Game</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: @sandy b have you tried my solution?